# Using arrays to make execute loop command and turn columns to variables

Tags: arrays, bash, perl, awk

Want to have three arrays per row and to catch all of them and turn to variables which can I use in execute a command with those values in loop.

Array example "just what is in my mind I'm not so good in that" :

```
Arr =  [ dba, password, db1;
         dba, password, db2;                   
         dba, password, db3; ]
```

I want ";" to be a some kind of separator of the loop not sure is it possible and when the loop is created to make something like that and to catch first second and third column:

```
sqlplus 1col[@]/2col[@]@3col[@]
```

Comment: Use an array of arrays.

Comment: It would be better to use an array of hashes. Arrays should be used for uniform data, hashes for heterogeneous collections.

Comment: You're telling us how you want to solve a problem, not what the problem is you're trying to solve, so the answers you get may not be the best solutions to your actual problem. Post some representative sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an array of hashes in Perl like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @settings = (
    { dba => 'dba1', pass => 'pass1', db => 'db1' },
    { dba => 'dba2', pass => 'pass2', db => 'db2' },
    { dba => 'dba3', pass => 'pass3', db => 'db3' }
);

for my $set (@settings) {
    system("sqlplus", "$set->{'dba'}/$set->{'pass'}\@$set->{'db'}");
}
```

This will execute `sqlplus dba1/pass1@db1`, then `sqlplus dba2/pass2@db2`, etc.

Comment: Is the executable in your `$PATH`? What should the command look like exactly?

Comment: the command should be like:

`sqlplus dba/password@db`

Anyway I execute the script with the oracle user and the environment is set.

Comment: Unfortunately only sqlplus command appear the values not showing. I checked with "ps" command and it's like that `oracle 24772896 45547804   0 10:51:54  pts/1  0:00 sqlplus`

Comment: I changed last row to:

`for my $set (@settings) { system "sqlplus $set->{'dba'}/$set->{'pass'}\@$set->{'db'}\n"; }`

And now is work for me.

Comment: @Kalin glad you got it working, I've updated my answer to use `system` as well.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to use array of array structure,

```
my @Arr = (
     [qw( dba password db1 )],
     [qw( dba password db2 )],               
     [qw( dba password db3 )],
);

# to access first array
print "$Arr[0][0], $Arr[0][1], $Arr[0][2]\n";
```

Comment: how to turn them in the loop

Comment: @KalinBorisov `for my $r (@Arr) { print "$r->[0], $r->[1], $r->[2]\n" }`

Comment: I get that error:
`1: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
1: line 1: `my @Arr = ('
`